# How to print a voucher with Java and a EPSON TM-T88III

Tags: java, printing, epson, javapos

I just bought an EPSON TM-T88III. Now I want to write a small application in java that prints a voucher with some plain text, so nothing special. I was wondering how I could do this.

So far I figured out that I can print simple documents using the Windows Drivers and Notepad. Do you recommend me to use the JavaPoS? It would be great to get some hints to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is so late, but I'm having a similar issue.

I recommend using an existing ESC/POS (the communication protocol) library.

This was enough to get me started, I simply did a port for my project (using a TM-T20)

https://code.google.com/p/escprinter/source/browse/trunk/net/drayah/matrixprinter/ESCPrinter.java?r=2